# Weird headlight issue!

Tags: honda, civic, headlight

I have a 1998 Honda Civic hatchback.

So this is my issue: I turned on my lights... my driver side works but my passenger light is out.

I hit switch for the high beam now the driver side headlight goes out (and is only the running light) but then the passenger side turns on and is a high beam.

I don't really know too much about cars and to be honest I haven't really looked. I was going to tomorrow. I just thought I'd get some opinions on what it could possibly be, so I have a plan of action for tomorrow and know what to look for.

Answer (score 7):

Each bulb usually has 2 filaments in it, one for low beam and one for high beam.   One possibility is that your driver's side bulb has a broken high beam filament and the passenger side has a broken low beam filament.

A search reveals that your headlight bulbs are likely of type H4 and look like the following.  They match my description above.  This video shows the replacement of one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqxOYVHAUQ8

If you swap the bulbs over, the described fault should move with the bulbs.  If not, you have a different problem.

[image]